# The modal works for one product, but the duplicate does not

Tags: javascript, modal-dialog

I created a popup modal for one of the products (Products section). The first one works fine, I duplicated the others but they don't work. What could be the problem, what did I screw up?

Link: https://vth5mr.csb.app/

I copied the same code multiple times that works.

HTML code:
`

```
                <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/G2NtGgG7/products-1.png" alt="products image" class="products-img">
                <div class="modal">
                    <button class="modal-button" id="open-modal">
                        <i class="ri-arrow-right-up-line"></i>
                      </button>
                <div class="modal-container" id="modal-container">
                  <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-close close-modal" title="close">
                      <i class="ri-close-line"></i>
                    </div>

                    <img src="https://i.postimg.cc/3xJkr6nF/Jackass-biiters-front-label.jpg" alt="modal image" class="modal-img">
                  </div>
                </div>
                </div>
                <h3 class="products-name">Jackass Bitters</h3>
                <span class="products-price">$10.00</span>
              </article>`
```

Javascript code:

```js
const showModal = (openButton, modalContent) => {
  const openBtn = document.getElementById(openButton),
    modalContainer = document.getElementById(modalContent);

  if (openBtn && modalContainer) {
    openBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      modalContainer.classList.add("show-modal");
    });
  }
};

showModal("open-modal", "modal-container");

/*=============== CLOSE MODAL ===============*/
const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".close-modal");

function closeModal() {
  const modalContainer = document.getElementById("modal-container");
  modalContainer.classList.remove("show-modal");
}

closeBtn.forEach((c) => c.addEventListener("click", closeModal));
```

Comment: Please include the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" code in the question itself.

Comment: Did you have a chance to check this out? Maybe mark an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **Element id's must be unique** & make sure listeners applied correctly

You have multiple modal elements with the same id, `id="open-modal"` and `id="modal-container"`, however these need to be unique in every instance. Like: `open-modal1`, `open-modal2`, `open-modal3`, etc.

In general, it's a universal rule that every `id=` on your entire page ***must*** be unique. No exceptions.

Also 1: In your page's JS it looks like you're only applying a click listener to the first instance of a modal button (the first product). In contrast, further in code I do see a close listener applied to all modal close instances: `const closeBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".close-modal")`. I'd expect a similar `querySelectorAll` to be applied to modal open buttons. Similarly, the open logic should be wrapped in a function just like your `function closeModal() {...`.

Also 2: You have other errors coming up in console, especially when scrolling. Although it may be a separate issue, there's a chance this could be blocking other functionality on the page.